# Oauth2 in server-side access/refresh token

Tags: java, python, firebase, oauth, oauth-2.0

We are trying to implement `Oauth2` on our app, in our App we are login using `Sign In with Google`, and this returns a lot of stuff like : `UID`, `ACCESS_TOKEN`, `REFRESH_TOKEN`, etc.. we are thinking to send from APP to server-side the `UID` and store it to DB linked with user like if it was its password.

From server side we want to on each call for instance : get_products, we are thinking to use an `access_token` but we don't know if it's the `UID` from user itself or we have to create another `access_token` with its `refres_token` with expiration time. So we have one `UID` from user and another `access_token` and `refresh_token` from oauth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the value you refer by `UID`. May be it's something that I haven't come across before.

But if it stands for USER IDENTIFIER, then you should not use it to identify the end user and maintain a session. UID could be a public identifier so anyone who knows will be able to communicate to your server. Also, think about user login through multiple devices. Your server won't be able to identify the correct session.

User `access_token` to initiate a session. In your server, use [user-information endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validate-access-token) to obtain validity details and end user information. Alternatively you may choose OpenID Connect.